# How to add background color on number picker Selected text Flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, picker, numberpicker

Whenever I tried to add background color to this it hides the selected text. Need Solution

```dart
NumberPicker(
  value: restDisplayedSec,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 59,
  step: 1,
  itemHeight: 30,
  selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
  onChanged: (value) => setState(
    () {
      restDisplayedSec = value;
      secLengthRest = restDisplayedSec +
          restDisplayedMin *
              60; //als Methode weil 2x vorkommt?
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Are you using `numberpicker` pkg?

Comment: @md-yeasin-sheikh Yes brother

Comment: Which part of the code is the background color? What does the result look like? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: I have checked the source code, I think there are better ways to handle the decoration on that pkg  Can you include an image what are you trying to get